# What's wrong with this python prime number function?

Tags: python, function, numbers, primes

So I just want to check what's wrong with my function. It gives out prime numbers just fine but when I put in a number like 4, it prints "4 is not prime" then "4 is a prime number."
What seems to be the error? (I know it's sad, but I spent 8 hours doing this(beginner)).

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        print ("1 is not prime.")
    if n == 2:
        print ("2 is a prime number.")
    for x in range (2, n):
        if n%x == 0:
            print (n, "is not prime.")
        if n%x != 0:
            print (n, "is a prime number.")
```

Comment: You'll want to return `True` or `False` from your function and then print depending on that. Otherwise you'll get several printings.

Comment: Check the solution here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: Apart from the correct answers below, remember especially when bug hunting to print out everything you care about-- in this case, x too. "print (n, " is not prime; it divides by ", x)" would reveal your bug instantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong, you need to break after a factor is detected, and print is a prime if there are no factors.

Here's a corrected version:

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        print ("1 is not prime.")
        return
    if n == 2:
        print ("2 is a prime number.")
        return
    for x in range (2, n):
        if n%x == 0:
            print (n, "is not prime.")
            break
    else:
        print (n, "is a prime number.")
```

Comment: … although in this case, you could just use `return` instead of `break`, and not need the `else`. (Still, it's a good demonstration of what `for…else` is useful for in general.)

Comment: Meanwhile, this is still buggy. For 1, it will print "1 is not prime." or "2 is a prime number.", and then it will fall through to the `for` statement, loop 0 times, hit the `else`, and print `"1 is a prime number". And likewise for `2`. You either need to add `return` statements to those `if` bodies, or change it to an `if`/`elif`/`else` (with the `for…else` loop inside the `else`).

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `break` statement right under `print(n, "is not prime.")`, otherwise it will continue to loop through all the numbers until n, which would be unnecessary.